# Delete range of rows using generate_series()?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-delete, generate-series

To update every row in a table, I use this query (and it's working):

[image]

I wonder if I can use a similar notation for `DELETE`?

Something like:

```
DELETE from test2
from generate_series(1, 1000) as idx
WHERE id = idx;
```

Won't work as the second `FROM` is invalid, of course. Any idea how to fix that?

What is the best practice for this kind of operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `USING`:

```
DELETE from test2 
       using generate_series(1, 1000) idx
       WHERE id = idx
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best practice for this kind of operation?

You *can* use [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) like Gordon demonstrates. This might even make sense for non-integer types or with an increment <> 1.
For simple cases, the simple query is superior, though:

```sql
DELETE FROM test2 
WHERE  id BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;
```